# Modeling with sinusoidal functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have difficulty understanding when the amplitude will become negative/postive for the following questions.

I knew how to calculate the amplitude but I am not very sure on how to determine the +/- signs of the amplitude

Question A
[image]
Question B
[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Are you asking why the sign was chosen in the solution for each of the problems?

Comment: Hi Moo, yes. I cant tell when is the amplitude negative or positive.

Comment: I will walk you through the first one and then you can try to follow and do the second as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question A, We are given the relation:

$$S(t) = a\sin(b~t) + d$$

We are also told that $t$ is given in days, but for the sine function, we need arguments to be in radians, so we can find $b$ as:

$$b = \dfrac{2 \pi}{365 ~~\mbox{days}}$$

We are given that at $t = 0$, we have an average value of $\$3.47$, which leads to:

$$S(0) = a \sin 0 + d = 3.47 \implies d = 3.47$$

So, we now have the relation:

$$S(t) = a \sin\left(\dfrac{2 \pi}{365}t\right) + 3.47$$

Now, if we had another data point, we can find $a$, and they happen to tell us that at $t = 91.25$ days, we have an average value of $\$1.97$, so we have:

$$S(91.25) = a \sin\left(\dfrac{2 \pi}{365}~91.25\right) + 3.47 = 1.97\implies a = -1.5$$

As you can see, we did not have to guess at anything, we calculated the sign of the amplitude from the given information.

This gives us the final result as:

$$S(t) = -1.5 ~\sin\left(\dfrac{2 \pi}{365}t\right) + 3.47$$

Now, give the second one a go.